# Why is printed 1?

Tags: java, try-finally

I have code:

```
class Test {
  public static void main(final String [] args) {
    System.out.println(foo());
  }

  private static int foo() {
    int a = 0;
      try {
        ++a;
        return a;
      } finally {
        a = 10;
      }
    }
  }
```

I can't uderstand why 1 is printed.

Comment: if you want to return 10 add return 10; in finally block

Comment: i think you are confused with fianlly block. take a look over here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html

Comment: I want understand why 1 is printed.

Answer (score 6):

```
try {
    ++a;
    return a; // 1 is returned here
} finally {
    a = 10; // a is assigned with 10 later.
}
```

The value of `a` is incremented and returned in the `try` block itself. Post this `return`, the value of `a` is re-assigned in the `finally` block. And that is the reason, why it prints *1*.

---

Quoting from the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-3.html#jvms-3.13). This should help you understand it more clearly.

**Compiling finally**

Compilation of a try-finally statement is similar to that of try-catch. Prior to transferring control outside the try statement, whether that transfer is normal or abrupt, because an exception has been thrown, the finally clause must first be executed. For this simple example:

```
void tryFinally() {
    try {
        tryItOut();
    } finally {
        wrapItUp();
    }
}
```

The compiled code is:

```
Method void tryFinally()
0   aload_0             // Beginning of try block
1   invokevirtual #6    // Method Example.tryItOut()V
4   jsr 14              // Call finally block
7   return              // End of try block
8   astore_1            // Beginning of handler for any throw
9   jsr 14              // Call finally block
12  aload_1             // Push thrown value
13  athrow              // ...and rethrow value to the invoker
14  astore_2            // Beginning of finally block
15  aload_0             // Push this
16  invokevirtual #5    // Method Example.wrapItUp()V
19  ret 2               // Return from finally block
Exception table:
From    To      Target      Type
0       4       8           any
```

There are four ways for control to pass outside of the try statement:

1. by falling through the bottom of that block
2. by returning
3. by executing a break or continue statement
4. by raising an exception.

Comment: How it is possible? How we can assign new value after return?

Comment: That's not true, The main reason is they are in different block. You will see a compiler error if you do the same in same block. @frostjogla look at my edit.

Comment: @R.J I know that finally block always executed after try block. I can't uderstat how it possible? How does this JVM?

Comment: I've edited the answer to add some part of the docs. I hope that helps you.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the `finally` block of a try..catch..finally runs after the code within the `try..catch` has completed

You are assigned the value in `finally` and before that you returned in `try`

The code in finally always executes,but you are already returned the value in `try`.

```
try {
    ++a;
    return a; 
  } finally {
    a = 10; 
  }
```

Now `a` value is `10`, after the `return`.
Though not a good practice, Just for demo.

```
int a= 0;
try {
    ++a;
    return a; 
  } finally {
    a = 10;
    return a;
  }
```

Now it `return`'s `10`.

**Edit:**

**Your doubt :** Why unreacable error not coming ?

in `try-catch-finally` the blocks are different. Do the same in same block and see.

```
try {
            ++a;
            return a;
            a=100;  //compiler error.
          } finally {
            a = 10;
          }
```

**Edit2**

From [java language specification of try-catch-finally :](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20)

> A try statement executes a block. If a value is thrown and the try statement has one or more catch clauses that can catch it, then control will be transferred to the first such catch clause. If the try statement has a finally clause, then another block of code is executed, no matter whether the try block completes normally or abruptly, and no matter whether a catch clause is first given control.

Comment: How it is possible? How we can assign new value after return?

Comment: @frostjogla in try-catch-finally the blocks are different. Do the same in same block and see. look my edit part.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Test {
  public static void main(final String [] args) {
    System.out.println(foo());
  }

  private static int foo() {
    int a = 0;
      try {
        ++a;
        return a;
      } finally {
        a = 10;
      }
    }
  }
```

In the above code, value returned will be 1 because, finally will not update the value returned in the try block.

```
class Test {
  public static void main(final String [] args) {
    System.out.println(foo());
  }

  private static int foo() {
    int a = 0;
      try {
        ++a;
        return a;
      } finally {
        a = 10;
    return a;
      }
    }
  }
```

The above code will return the value as 10, because, the value is returned from finally again.

Answer (score 0):

JVM is a stack-based machine. It push and pop value onto the stack. I decompiled `Test` class, to understand how it work.

```
private static int foo();
 Code:
   0: iconst_0        //push 0 to stack
   1: istore_0        //store 0 in the local variable 'a'(numbered 0). a==0
   2: iinc      0, 1  //increase the local variable 'a'(numbered 0) by 1. a==1;
   5: iload_0         //push value of the local variable 'a' onto the stack;
   6: istore_1        //store 1 in the local variable that not be declared(numbered 1);
   7: bipush    10    //push 10 onto the stack;
   9: istore_0        //store 10 in the local variable 'a'
  10: iload_1         //push onto stack value==1 of local variable that not be declared
  11: ireturn         //return 1
  12: astore_2
  13: bipush   10
  15: istore_0
  16: aload_2
  17: athrow
 Exception table:
 // not interesting ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply...you have not mentioned **return a**  ***in*** or after ***final block***.
Final block is executed in the end and value of a is set to 10, but you have not coded to return this new value!
Try below code to get your expected output:

```
class Test {
  public static void main(final String [] args) {
    System.out.println(foo());
  }

  private static int foo() {
    int a = 0;
      try {
        ++a;
        return a;
      } finally {
        a = 10;
       return a;
      }
    }
  }
```