# Behaviour of return in try catch finally

Tags: java

In following code I want to understand the the behaviour of `return` statement.`Finally` block will always execute so this function will always `return 30` ,but what is significance of return statement in try block.Does this return in try block return value to its caller, which will store this value  in some stack and replaced when it see a return statement in `finally` block? or  return in try block will call `finally` block?

```
public static int test() {
    try {
           return 10;// to whom this 10 is returned to?
    } catch (Exception e) {
       return 20;
    }finally{
           System.out.println("Finally");
       return 30;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is printed 1?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19651860/why-is-printed-1)

Comment: Just as a warning: `finally` is meant for cleaning up resources and not for control flow. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48088/returning-from-a-finally-block-in-java and the topics linked from there for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Both `10` and `30` will return. But `30` is on top of the `stack`(top most element). so caller get the return value as `30`.

Answer (score 1):

`finally` block should be used for *resource clearing* only, e.g.

```
  public static int test() {
    MyResource resource = null;

    try {
      // resource allocation
      MyResource resource = MyResource.allocate();

      ... // do something with the resource

      return 10; // <- Normal flow
    } 
    catch(MyResourceException e) {
      ... // something was wrong with resource

      return 20; // <- Abnormal, but expected flow
    }
    finally {
      // In any case - has an exception (including errors) been thrown or not 
      // we have to release allocated resource 

      // The resource has been allocated 
      if (resource != null)
        resource.release();

      // no return here: finally is for resource clearing only
    }
  }
```

in case you put `return 30` into finally *both values* (say, `10` and `30`) will be
put to stack; but since `30` will be on the top of the stack you'll see `30`.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `finally` block will always be executed in your case for cleaning the reources the ouptut will be 30 since it will be on top of the stack. However if you want to come out of your try block directly then you may use `System.exit()`